# rlang::parse_expr with string with escape characters

Tags: string, metaprogramming, rlang

how I could use `eval(rlang::parse_expr(string))’ or alternative with  such expresssion` string <-"print('A\s*B')"`? I am getting unrecognized escape character. The expression is evaluated inside function, print is an example, I am using grepl in similar manier.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using second escape slash helped "print('A\s*B')"